# Connecting PHP-FPM with Nginx in Docker Compose

Tags: php, docker, nginx, docker-compose, alpine-linux

I'm fiddling with Docker, trying to setup a Docker composition with Nginx and PHP-FPM running on separate Alpine containers. My setup is available on GitHub at https://github.com/sparkbuzz/lemp_docker, my **docker-compose.yml** looks as follows:

```
version: '3'
services:
  alpine_nginx:
    build: ./nginx
    container_name: alpine_nginx
    links:
      - alpine_php
    ports:
      - "80:80"

  alpine_php:
    build: ./php
    container_name: alpine_php
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"
```

I am able to build the images successfully, and when I visit localhost in my browser, I can see the index.html served by Nginx. However, when trying to access phpinfo.php, I get a **502 - Bad Gateway** error

I can `docker exec -it ... /bin/ash` into both the running instances, and it seems the services are running happily, however, it's clear PHP-FPM on port 9000 is never even hit.

Here's some feedback from my console:

````
Recreating alpine_php ...
Recreating alpine_php ... done
Recreating alpine_nginx ...
Recreating alpine_nginx ... done
Attaching to alpine_php, alpine_nginx
alpine_php      | [06-Nov-2017 21:46:39] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
alpine_php      | [06-Nov-2017 21:46:39] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
alpine_nginx    | 2017/11/06 21:46:46 [error] 6#6: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.20.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://172.20.0.2:9000", host: "localhost"
alpine_nginx    | 172.20.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2017:21:46:46 +0000] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 502 568 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/61.0.3163.100 Safari/537.36" "-"```
````

I'm so close, but not sure why Nginx isn't happy with the PHP upstream. Nginx config is as follows:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name localhost;

  location / {
    root /var/www/localhost/htdocs/;
    index index.html;
  }

  location ~* \.php$ {
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass alpine_php:9000;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
  }
}
```

How do I get Nginx talking to PHP FPM?

Comment: what does your upstream configuration look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are listen `127.0.0.1` in your php-fpm config.

Add this to `php/Dockerfile`

```
RUN sed -i 's/127.0.0.1:9000/0.0.0.0:9000/g' /etc/php7/php-fpm.d/www.conf
```

Comment: Wow, that fixed it, I need to do some homework on 127.0.0.1 vs 0.0.0.0, as I thought they were the same. Thanks for your answer @nuster

Comment: @josef.van.niekerk `0.0.0.0` means listen for connections from everywhere, `127.0.0.1` means listen for connections from loopback (same machine)